# Cypress Custom Command - Break from a .each() loop and return a value to be used in further steps

Tags: cypress

I am new to Cypress [3 days :)]. I am creating a custom command which is trying to find the column index of column in a table.
I want to return the column index and store it in a variable and use it in future steps.

Here is what I have tried:

```
    Cypress.Commands.add('get_table_column_index', (columnName) => {

  cy.getIframeBody().find('table').within(() => {
    cy.get('tr th[scope=col]').each((element, index) => {
      let colName = element.text();
      cy.log(index, colName);
      
      if(colName == columnName)
      {
        cy.wrap(index).as('index');
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
});

let columnIndex = cy.get_table_column_index('ColName').get('@index');
cy.log('index' + columnIndex);
```

**index is [object Object]**

Can someone please guide me in resolving this issue?
What am I doing wrong?

I can see that `wrap` is returning the correct index value but I am not sure how to extract and use it.

=======  Update  =========

I tried this and looks like it was able to log the correct value:

```
let columnIndex = 
cy.get_table_column_index(column_name).get('@index');
columnIndex.then(index => cy.log(index));
```

Now, I am trying to expand it to use the index value in the next step like this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('get_text', (row_num, column_name) => {
    
    let txt;
    cy.test_index(column_name).get('@index').then(index => {
        let element = cy.get('main > table').within(() => {
            cy.log('${index');
                        cy.get('tr:nth-child(${row_num}) td:nth-child(${index})');
        //txt = element.text();
        cy.log(txt);
        });
    });
    return txt;
  })
```

I am not able to figure out how to use the value of `index` and `row_num` in `cy.get('tr:nth-child(${row_num}) td:nth-child(${index})';` expression.

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change the way that you are using variable.

```
 cy.log(this.index + columnIndex);
```

Comment: Looks like the the `this` keyword is not working. Getting the following error:
`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'index')`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working like this:

```
.get('@index').then(....
```

was used to extract the value of the index which is returned by my method `get_table_column_index`.

Then used `cy.wrap` again to return the cell value.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('get_text', (row_num, column_name) => {

cy.get_table_column_index(column_name).get('@index').then(index => {
    cy.get('main > table').within(() => {
     cy.get(`tr:nth-child(${row_num}) td:nth-child(${index})`)
        .invoke('text')
        .then((text) => {
            cy.log("Text = " + text);
            return cy.wrap(text).as('cell_value');
        })
    });
});
```

})

Then finally in my method call:

```
let cell_text = cy.get_text(2, 'Licensing').get('@cell_value');
cell_text.then(cell_value => {
    cy.log(cell_value);
    expect(cell_value).to.include('QTP');
})
```

The only thing I am not able to do is to store the value in a variable and use it without chaining any command like `then` to extract its value.

It would be great if someone can provide more information on that.

Thanks.